# Where API credentials should be stored in laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, package

We are developing package for laravel which interact with another app through API. Currently we are storing api credentials in cache.  Whenever cache get cleared connection break. We are thinking for alternative .
Is this good practice to store those credentials in database? if yes how it will get refresh for next credentials?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend adding a config file for them which loads them from the .env file. You can largely mimic the database credential infrastructural for this. This allows you to isolate the information in a single file, and keep them out of git completely. It also allows you to modify them per environment if you have a separate endpoint and/or credentials for the api which you can use in local or any uat environments.

.env:

```
THIRD_PARTY_API_USERNAME=test
THIRD_PARTY_API_PASSWORD=test
```

config/third-party.php

```
<?php

return [
  'username' => env('THIRD_PARTY_API_USERNAME', null),
  'password' => env('THIRD_PARTY_API_PASSWORD', null),
];
```

usage:

```
$password = config('third_party.password');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have enough control over your caching mechanism, to ensure when it's cleared, right?

On the other hand, surely you can use a database. Just make a new table where you store at least the key and a timestamp. This way you can always find out how old the key is and just replace it by a new one.